# Possible behaviours of the cofinality-of-neighbourhood function for topological spaces $X$ that are connected.

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Given a topological space $X,$ there is a function $f_X : X \rightarrow \mathrm{Cardinals}$ defined as follows. Given a point $x \in X$, $f_X(x)$ is the [cofinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinality) of the poset whose elements are the neighbourhoods of $x,$ whose order relation is reverse-inclusion. (So $U \leq V$ iff $U \supseteq V$).

For example, to say that $X$ is *first-countable* is just to say that $f_X(x) \leq \aleph_0$ for all $x \in X$.

> **Specific question.** What is an example of a connected topological space $X$ where $f_X$ is not constant?
>
> **General question.** What is known about the possible behaviors of $f_X$ when $X$ is connected?

Comment: Interesting! Is this question in the context of a larger question, or is there some source you can provide for this question?

Comment: @CameronBuie, not really man. The context is just that I recently stumbled upon the concept of a first-countable space, which suggested the definition of $f_X$, which suggested the question of what possible behaviors $f_X$ is capable of.

Comment: What topology are you giving to the class of cardinals? Also, what Choice Principles (if any) are you taking for granted?

Comment: @CameronBuie, I've changed the specific question a bit to make it clearer. It now reads: "What is an example of a connected topological space $X$ where $f_X$ is not constant?" (Use any choice principles desired, such as the full axiom of choice or even global choice.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cardinal function is better known as the [*character*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)#Weight_and_character) of a topological space at a point, and is denoted $\chi$.

For an example of a connected space where $\chi$ is not constant, consider the "[extended long ray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology))" $X = ( \omega_1 \times [0,1) ) \cup \{ \langle \omega_1 , 0 \rangle \}$ with the (lexicographic) order topology.  It is pretty clear that $\chi ( X ; \langle \alpha , x \rangle ) = \aleph_0$ for all $\langle \alpha , x \rangle \in \omega_1 \times [0,1)$, however $\chi ( X ; \langle \omega_1 , 0 \rangle ) = \aleph_1$.

(I am unaware of any restrictions on this cardinal function in the class of connected spaces. Well, I guess $\chi ( X ; x )$ cannot be finite if $X$ is a connected Hausdorff space of size $>1$, but that's not really saying much.)